# What kind of VB6 file generates a data report?

Tags: vb6

Please, I would like to know what kind of vb6 or vb file generates DataReport. For example vb calender is generated by MSCAL.OCX, vb dataGrid is generated by MSDATGRD.OCX, CommonDialog is generated by COMDLG32.OCX, ms data report designer v6.0 is generated by MSDBRPT.DLL

Comment: Writing your question in caps will not get you a swifter answer. Rather, it will make people think you are an idiot, and someone to be avoided.

Comment: @MusiGenesis You make my case perfectly.

Comment: Guys just edit the caps out - don't stand around shouting....

Comment: @Preet -- generally you want to add the edit message to the end of the post otherwise it pushes the question text out of the question page snippet.

Comment: @tvanfossen -- thank you, I appreciate the advice. Sorry for overwriting your edit - I think we did this at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB6 anymore but I think this may come from msdbrptr.dll.